RO Pressure Tank Not Filling
I just replaced a 22 gallon pressure tank at my work (it was waterlogged and would not empty when ball valve was opened). The new tank will not fill at all so the only water is what is stored in the lines and then runs out.
Here is how it is set up: Water in (35psi) to Scaling filter (replaced) to low pressure solenoid (3/8 cut) to pump (output measures 90psi) into pre/post membrane (36GPD) filter canister out to High pressure switch (40/60 cut-replaced as I believe this is what cause damage to tank because it wouldn't shut off pump even when closing Ball Valve) to tank (empty pressure factory set and checked @ 38psi) and 4 line out with polisher (also replaced). All filters and membrane Brand New today and seated properly (problem was there before changing). (Pump now shuts off when ball valve closed and yes it's now open).
No water will enter tank so I thought lowering the tank pressure would resolve the issue (tried 25psi) but still NO water in tank. I can't find anywhere what the proper pressure setting should be with this setup. Everything online is 6-8psi but it's for a 2 gallon tank not a 22 gallon tank. I'm at a loss, Any Thoughts?

Is the pump shutting off when the tank valve is open?

No, the pressure never reaches the 40psi mark. When I dropped pressure to 25, pressure never got passed 25

It should still be 6-8 PSI. Gallons don't enter into it.
Drain all water from the tank and reduce the pressure to 6-8. Reattach water and the tank will fill.

Really? Awesome, I will try tomorrow morning. I was afraid to try this because I was afraid it would damage the diaphragm. On another note, would a 100 GPD membrane help any ( this services 80 people - coffee pods, water coolers)?

@FrankC. Help? Help fill the tank? If there is some other problem like frequently running out of RO water, I think you should start a new question and explain the problem in detail. This question is about the tank not filling.
